# Apex zune for VS2012 or 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, pivot, visual-studio-2013

Hello I would like to use the [Apex package](http://apex.codeplex.com/) on VS2013 but it seems like its impossible.

I really like this design

[image]

It looks like its a pivot control like on windows phone but its not allowed for wpf, since im not a pro (still at school) where could i get a control like this for wpf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to install just fine for me in a test WPF project in VS 2013.  I just right click on my project and went to Manage NuGet, searched for 'Apex' in the online section and clicked Install.  What issues were you having?

[image]